# Unable to access the application settings of my azure app service from my blazor app

Tags: azure-web-app-service, blazor-webassembly

I´m deploying a Blazor WebAssembly application on an azure App service. I would like to define on the application settings some variables containing secret keys. The problem is that my Blazor app doesn't see these variables when I put them on the app service application settings. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. These are the variables defined on a slot inside my app service:

app service screenshot

[image]

And this is the configuration on the Program.cs of my blazor app that is related to the apps I´m trying to use:

```
    services.AddMsalAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount>(options =>
    {
        options.ProviderOptions.Authentication.Authority = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAdB2CAuthority");
        options.ProviderOptions.Authentication.ClientId = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAdB2CClientId");
        options.ProviderOptions.Authentication.ValidateAuthority = builder.Configuration.GetValue<bool>("AzureAdB2CValidateAuthority");
        //builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
        options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("openid");
        options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("offline_access");
        options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("XXXX");
        options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
    })
            .AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteAuthenticationState,CustomUserAccount, CustomAccountFactory>();
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated. I have been stuck on this a whole week ...

Right now my appsettings.json looks like this:

```
{

  "AzureAdB2CAuthority": "XXXXXXXXXX",
  "AzureAdB2CClientId": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "AzureAdB2CValidateAuthority": false
}
```

**EDIT**

I'm getting this error when I try to rename these variables on my application settings. Any idea why? Could it be an issue with my plan?

[Error renaming variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GlKl.png)

Comment: Try this one: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configuring-a-server-side-blazor-app-with-azure-app-configuration/ | the base name is not enought. You can use MainSettings.SideSettings.SideSettings2 format. It can work with dot, underline or with colon.

Comment: Can you attach your app settings to your question?

Comment: @KKI I had the same variables defined on my appsettings.json but with with different values. I read that the app service settings override those values, but that is not happening. I confirmed this because I removed these variables from my appsettings.json and my blazor app stopped working because it can´t see them.

Comment: They are at the top level of JSON, not sub elements of something, is it right? (AzureAdB2CAuthority, AzureAdB2CClientId, AzureAdB2CValidateAuthority)

Comment: @KKi That is correct. My first attempt had those variables as sub elements, that would be the right way, but on my many attempts I placed the variables at the top level of the JSON just to check that was not the problem.

Comment: Try this one: `APPSETTING_AzureAdB2CAuthority` on the Azure portal as application settings (and your value for sure). | But its weird because your assumption is correct, that should work fine.

Comment: Maybe the problem is the name. Try it without "Azure" in the name of the json line.

Comment: I get the following error when I try to save the variable with that name: "Failed to update web app settings: AppSetting with name 'APPSETING_AzureAdB2CAuthority' is not allowed"

Comment: I also tried to remove the "Azure" part from the name... still not working

Comment: You need to access the values as `builder.Configuration["AzureAdB2CAuthority"];`

Comment: thanks for your answer @Harshitha. I tried that also and its not working...

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Iam able to access the value. Will post an answer in detail.

Comment: Iam able to access with both  `builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("APPSETTING_AzureAdB2CAuthority ");` and `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_AzureAdB2CAuthority");`

Comment: After adding the appsettings restart the app once and check.

Comment: Still nothing, I´m not able to rename the variables on the slot with the prefix "APPSETTING_", please see the edit I added. I also tried to access those variables with that prefix from my Blazor code (even if the variables on the slot don´t have it) and is not working either. After each change I have restarted the app service...

Comment: Do not Edit the values with appsetting prefix.Just add with key name `AzureAdB2CAuthority`..same like which you have added initially.This key itself you can see it as appsetting prefix in kudu

Comment: Just retrieve the value using appsetting prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @ KKI for the comment.

Yes, the values set in Environment Variables section is appended with prefix `APPSETTING`.

You can check it in KUDU Console => Environment Variables.

[image]

Iam able to access the value with both

```cs
 builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("APPSETTING_AzureAdB2CAuthority ");
```

and

```cs
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPSETTING_AzureAdB2CAuthority");
```

and able to login without any issues.

***Output:***
[image]

### Update:

- Do not add the Environmental Variable with `APPSETTING_` prefix. It will not allow you to add keys with `_`.
- Just add the key as shown below(which you have done initially).

[image]

- The above key which you set without any prefix, if you check in KUDU, you can see the `APPSETTING_` prefix is updated to the key.
- Install `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables`    Nuget package.
- Add `AddEnvironmentVariables` in the `ConfigurationBuilder`.

***My `Program.cs` file:***

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

var configBuild = new ConfigurationBuilder();
   
configBuild.AddEnvironmentVariables();

var configuration = configBuild.Build();

-------

builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{  
  options.ProviderOptions.Authentication.Authority = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAdB2CAuthority");
  options.ProviderOptions.Authentication.ClientId = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAdB2CClientId");
  options.ProviderOptions.Authentication.ValidateAuthority = builder.Configuration.GetValue<bool>("AzureAdB2CValidateAuthority");

});
await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

By adding `AddEnvironmentVariables` and the above code config in `Program.cs` file, you can directly retrieve the value using `builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureAdB2CAuthority")`.

Comment: @b-612 - Please check the update section in the answer.